# disable button and re enabling when condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following button in an Aspx page

```
 <button type="button" style="margin: 10px;" class='btn btn-xs btn-warning'  onclick="RunIntegrationTest('<%=obj.Tab.Replace(" ", "")%>')">TestRun</button>
```

and here's the function from the JS

```
function RunIntegrationTest(tableNames) {
    c = confirm("Are you sure you want to Run Test?");
    if (c) {
        $('#LoadingModal').modal('show');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Shared/_RunIntegrationTestMainPage?tableNames=' + tableNames,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (res) {
                $('#LoadingModal').modal('hide');
                $('#GeneralModal').find('div.modal-title').text('Successfull');
                $('#GeneralModal').find('div.modal-body').html('<p>Run Worked, please refresh the page to see updates</p>');
                $('#GeneralModal').modal('show');
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#LoadingModal').modal('hide');
                $('#ErrorModal').modal('show');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

here's the class for the button

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tableNames = Request.QueryString["tableNames"].ToString();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableNames))
    {
        string sql = "";
        foreach (string table in tableNames.Split(','))
        {
            sql += " EXEC Run_"+table
        }
        SqlCmd cmd = new SqlCmd(sql);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    Response.Write("OK");
}
```

}

the button is a dynamic button that will be added to any table that I add in the default, it's work is that it run any stored procedure that i added with the table name.
the stored procedure is a trigger type that will update the database

what I'm trying to do is when one button is pressed the other buttons on the other tables get disabled till the update of the database finish.

How can I achieve that? I don't want a timer because that won't achieve the purpose of the function

Thank you in advance

Comment: So you want the other buttons to be disabled, when the user click `confirm` and then enable the again when the AJAX returns `success`?

Comment: yes that's what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: so, `if (c) {` disable buttons - `success: function.. etc` enable buttons again, and the same in error, should work right?

Comment: i'm trying but it's not working maybe i'm doing something wrong ? the button itself is working but the `disabled = true` is not working

Comment: how does your `disabled` get generated?  can you show us?

Comment: this is what i'm trying to do
`document.getElementById("TestRun").disabled = true;`

I have one button for 4 tables and it's dynamic but when i press any button only the first one get disabled

Comment: well.. you have jQuery - so `$('.yourSelector button').prop("disabled", true);` could maybe work.

Comment: `getElementById("TestRun")` and "only first one" - of course only first one as IDs must be unique so getelementbyid only gets the first one.  Move `id=TestRun` to `class=TestRun` and then `$(".TestRun").prop("disabled", true)`

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I have a question it work and i'm using a while statement to make the button `disable = false` but my problem is if I do a simple refresh for the page the buttons will work again even if i'm not using `disable = false` so what's the solution for this?

Comment: I solved the problem with asp:button and another stored procedure to check the value thank you all for the help